# Can Order armour skins be used by characters from different Orders?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If my Ranger is in the Order of Whispers, I buy some of their armour and thus unlock that armours skin across my account, can my other Ranger, who is a member of the Durmand priory, then use that skin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use all skins of armors (and weapons) that have been unlocked account-wide for all your characters, even if they are in different orders.

Comment: On a related note: order weapons can be used by characters of other orders, too.

Comment: The only exception to this rule is cultural armour, which is race-limited.